# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str' for Lambda sorting dictionary funtion Python

Tags: python, function, sorting, dictionary, lambda

I'm stuck with above error statement for the program below. The program should sort a dictionary by value (descending) and if values are the same, alphabetically (ascending).

```py
sorted(dict, key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

If I make a change:

```py
sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

it does work but it will print the value as well. I just want a list of the keys.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you just want the the keys, use .keys() on the sorted dict and get only the keys.

Comment: why you are using a dictionary if you just want the keys...? isn't it easier to use a list?

Comment: It looks like the keys in `sc2` are strings, so `x[1]` is a `str` (single char), and also x[0]. show us `sc2`. In any case `x[1]` is a `str`.

Comment: Changing `sc2` to `sc2.items()` is not a "tiny" change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify your approach slightly. What you have operates on `tuple`s from `items` and returns `tuple`s. You want to operate on the keys and return only the keys.

```py
>>> # let sc2 be:
>>> sc2 = {'aaa': 10, 'bcd': 5, 'abc': 10, 'cde': 1}
>>>
>>> # your approach:
>>> sorted(sc2.items(), key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[('aaa', 10), ('abc', 10), ('bcd', 5), ('cde', 1)]
>>>
>>> # see this one:
>>> sorted(sc2, key = lambda x: (-sc2[x], x))
['aaa', 'abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like where you have to check comparison on multiple conditions like: if first parameter is same then compare on basis of another parameter and so on.
You can use `comparator` in python to write the sorting logic like shown below:

```
import functools

sc2 = {'wsd': 10, 'bcd': 5, 'abc': 10, 'cde': 1}

def my_cmp(a,b):
    if sc2[a] == sc2[b]:
        return -1 if a > b else 1
    elif sc2[a] > sc2[b]:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

s = sorted(sc2, key=functools.cmp_to_key(my_cmp), reverse=True)

Output:-> ['abc', 'wsd', 'bcd', 'cde']
```